# Redirect with created id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've followed a few blog CRUD tutorials for Laravel, and I'm trying to advance to the next step by making a recipes website for myself.

The idea is that the user creates a new recipe, which contains the `title`, `description`, `portions`, `user_id` to the `recipes` table.

I've got this working, and it successfully saves to the db, along with the associated `tags` to the `recipe_tags` table.

I've currently got the `storeController` redirecting to the `recipe.show` view, which works fine, but I'm trying to get it to redirect to the `steps.create` view, and pull in the **title** and **description** from the db, and the associated `id` in the `recipes` table.

The following is my **store@recipesController:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required|max:255',
      'description' => 'required',
      'portions' => 'required'
    ]);

    $recipe = new Recipe;

    $recipe->name = $request->name;
    $recipe->description = $request->description;
    $recipe->portions = $request->portions;
    $recipe->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $recipe->save();

    if(isset($request->tags)){
      $recipe->tags()->sync($request->tags, true);
    } else {
      $post->tags()->sync([]);
    }

    return redirect()->route('steps.create', ['id' => $recipe->id]);
}
```

And this is my **create@stepsController**

```
public function create($id)
{
  $recipe = Recipe::find($id);
  return view('steps.create')->withRecipe($recipe);
}
```

But it's returning the following:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\StepsController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

I'm a bit out of my depth here. I think it may be an issue with my routes, (both of which are `Route::resource(...)`)

My fallback option is to use Ajax to write the recipe and steps to the database on the same page, but I'd rather learn how to do it the way I intended originally.

(EDIT: It's redirecting to the following URL in case that is of any significance.)

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/steps/create?id=3`

List of routes:

```
    $ php artisan route:list
    +--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
    | Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
    +--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
    |        | GET|HEAD  | /                      |                  | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@index                             | web          |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/user               |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | home                   | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
    |        | POST      | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
    |        | POST      | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
    |        | POST      | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
    |        | POST      | password/reset         |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | recipes                | recipes.index    | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@index                           | web,auth     |
    |        | POST      | recipes                | recipes.store    | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@store                           | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/create         | recipes.create   | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@create                          | web,auth     |
    |        | DELETE    | recipes/{recipe}       | recipes.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@destroy                         | web,auth     |
    |        | PUT|PATCH | recipes/{recipe}       | recipes.update   | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@update                          | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/{recipe}       | recipes.show     | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@show                            | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/{recipe}/edit  | recipes.edit     | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@edit                            | web,auth     |
    |        | POST      | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | steps                  | steps.index      | App\Http\Controllers\StepsController@index                             | web,auth     |
    |        | POST      | steps                  | steps.store      | App\Http\Controllers\StepsController@store                             | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | steps/create           | steps.create     | App\Http\Controllers\StepsController@create                            | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | steps/{step}           | steps.show       | App\Http\Controllers\StepsController@show                              | web,auth     |
    |        | PUT|PATCH | steps/{step}           | steps.update     | App\Http\Controllers\StepsController@update                            | web,auth     |
```

Comment: Can you show us the route? It seems that your URL is malformed (non-pretty), unsure if that causes any issues.

Comment: @Script47 I've updated the OP with route lists.

Comment: Your route name is steps.create...

Comment: Should it not be steps.show ??

Comment: I don't think so, as the steps haven't been created yet. The idea is to create the 'recipe' page, then add the steps to the recipe. Hence redirecting to the `steps.create` route.

Comment: The steps.create above does not take an id ... can you show your routes?

Comment: OP has been updated to include the route:list

Comment: I'm trying to store the recipe info, then redirect to the create steps page, and load the new recipe info on the new create steps page. I can't seem to pass the recipe info into the create steps page.

Comment: currently typing a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect route is passing 'id' as a GET Parameter so your controller can't understand that GET parameter as and $id variable, so you can solve it by doing this on your controller:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $recipe = Recipe::find($request->id);
    return view('steps.create')->withRecipe($recipe);
}
```

Comment: both $request->id or $request->input('id') should work

Comment: That's worked great, thanks! It's now displaying the correct view, and is showing the `{{$recipe->name}}` as expected.